# Websites with Search Fields - determining how to return full list

Tags: jquery, web, web-applications

I'm trying to determine how, when in a website that has a search field(s) which queries on table lists, to "crack the code" of what to place in the search field to return the entire list.  Until now, it's always been trial and error, but I'm beginning to come up short with that method.

For example, take this website: https://www.bop.gov/inmateloc/

The first and last name fields are required to perform a query.  I'm trying to determine what to enter into those fields to bring back the entire list.  Via Chrome's developer tools, I've determined the form is built with jquery.  Beyond that, I'm at a roadblock.  Is it possible that it's *not possible* to get the full list with this site?

Answer (score 2):

How search is implemented will vary from site to site, but any site which cares about data security or deals with large volumes of data will perform a server side search.

This means that what you type in the box is sent to the server, and only the hits are sent back to your browser. There will be no magic term to return all results, unless the developer has built it that way which is highly unlikely.

Comment: Thank you Phil, that's very helpful.